# limit web scraping extractions to once per xpath item, returning too many copies

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm using using the following [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) based web crawling script to extract some elements of [this page](http://tool.httpcn.com/Html/Zi/28/PWMETBAZTBTBBDTB.shtml), however, it's returning the same information over and over which is complicating the post processing I have to do, is there a good way to limit these extractions to once per xpath item?

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
#from hz_sample.items import HzSampleItem

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "hzIII"
    allowed_domains = ["tool.httpcn.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://tool.httpcn.com/Html/Zi/28/PWMETBAZTBTBBDTB.shtml"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//p")

        for titles in titles:
        tester = titles.xpath('//*[@id="div_a1"]/div[3][1]').extract()
        #jester = titles.xpath('//*[@id="div_a1"]/div[2]').extract() 
            print tester
```

[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ky2brjue84tx040/REPETITIVE.txt?dl=0) is what my output currently looks like (that's a link to a dropbox file).

The output should be the following:

```
[u'<div class="content16">\r\n<span class="zi18b">\u25ce \u57fa\u672c\u89e3\u91ca</span><br>\r\n\u6bd6 <br>b\xec <br>\u8c28\u614e\uff1a\u60e9\u524d\u6bd6\u540e\uff08\u63a5\u53d7\u8fc7\u53bb\u5931\u8d25\u7684\u6559\u8bad\uff0c\u4ee5\u540e\u5c0f\u5fc3\u4e0d\u91cd\u72af\uff09\u3002 <br>\u64cd\u52b3\uff1a\u201c\u65e0\u6bd6\u4e8e\u6064\u201d\u3002 <br>\u53e4\u540c\u201c\u6ccc\u201d\uff0c\u6cc9\u6c34\u5192\u51fa\u6d41\u6dcc\u7684\u6837\u5b50\u3002 <br> <br>\u7b14\u753b\u6570\uff1a9\uff1b <br>\u90e8\u9996\uff1a\u6bd4\uff1b <br>\u7b14\u987a\u7f16\u53f7\uff1a153545434 <br><br><br>\r\n</div>'] [u'<div class="text16"><span class="zi18b">\u25ce \u5b57\u5f62\u7ed3\u6784</span><br>[ <span class="b">\u9996\u5c3e\u5206\u89e3\u67e5\u5b57</span> ]\uff1a\u6bd4\u5fc5(bibi)\n\u3000[ <span class="b">\u6c49\u5b57\u90e8\u4ef6\u6784\u9020</span> ]\uff1a\u6bd4\u5fc5\n<br>[ <span class="b">\u7b14\u987a\u7f16\u53f7</span> ]\uff1a153545434<br>\n[ <span class="b">\u7b14\u987a\u8bfb\u5199</span> ]\uff1a\u6a2a\u6298\u6487\u6298\u637a\u6298\u637a\u6487\u637a<br>\n<br><hr class="hr"></div>']
```

but the current arrangement is returning that wanted output too many times, like so:

```
[u'<div class="content16">\r\n<span class="zi18b">\u25ce \u57fa\u672c\u89e3\u91ca</span><br>\r\n\u6bd6 <br>b\xec <br>\u8c28\u614e\uff1a\u60e9\u524d\u6bd6\u540e\uff08\u63a5\u53d7\u8fc7\u53bb\u5931\u8d25\u7684\u6559\u8bad\uff0c\u4ee5\u540e\u5c0f\u5fc3\u4e0d\u91cd\u72af\uff09\u3002 <br>\u64cd\u52b3\uff1a\u201c\u65e0\u6bd6\u4e8e\u6064\u201d\u3002 <br>\u53e4\u540c\u201c\u6ccc\u201d\uff0c\u6cc9\u6c34\u5192\u51fa\u6d41\u6dcc\u7684\u6837\u5b50\u3002 <br> <br>\u7b14\u753b\u6570\uff1a9\uff1b <br>\u90e8\u9996\uff1a\u6bd4\uff1b <br>\u7b14\u987a\u7f16\u53f7\uff1a153545434 <br><br><br>\r\n</div>'] [u'<div class="text16"><span class="zi18b">\u25ce \u5b57\u5f62\u7ed3\u6784</span><br>[ <span class="b">\u9996\u5c3e\u5206\u89e3\u67e5\u5b57</span> ]\uff1a\u6bd4\u5fc5(bibi)\n\u3000[ <span class="b">\u6c49\u5b57\u90e8\u4ef6\u6784\u9020</span> ]\uff1a\u6bd4\u5fc5\n<br>[ <span class="b">\u7b14\u987a\u7f16\u53f7</span> ]\uff1a153545434<br>\n[ <span class="b">\u7b14\u987a\u8bfb\u5199</span> ]\uff1a\u6a2a\u6298\u6487\u6298\u637a\u6298\u637a\u6487\u637a<br>\n<br><hr class="hr"></div>']
[u'<div class="content16">\r\n<span class="zi18b">\u25ce \u57fa\u672c\u89e3\u91ca</span><br>\r\n\u6bd6 <br>b\xec <br>\u8c28\u614e\uff1a\u60e9\u524d\u6bd6\u540e\uff08\u63a5\u53d7\u8fc7\u53bb\u5931\u8d25\u7684\u6559\u8bad\uff0c\u4ee5\u540e\u5c0f\u5fc3\u4e0d\u91cd\u72af\uff09\u3002 <br>\u64cd\u52b3\uff1a\u201c\u65e0\u6bd6\u4e8e\u6064\u201d\u3002 <br>\u53e4\u540c\u201c\u6ccc\u201d\uff0c\u6cc9\u6c34\u5192\u51fa\u6d41\u6dcc\u7684\u6837\u5b50\u3002 <br> <br>\u7b14\u753b\u6570\uff1a9\uff1b <br>\u90e8\u9996\uff1a\u6bd4\uff1b <br>\u7b14\u987a\u7f16\u53f7\uff1a153545434 <br><br><br>\r\n</div>'] [u'<div class="text16"><span class="zi18b">\u25ce \u5b57\u5f62\u7ed3\u6784</span><br>[ <span class="b">\u9996\u5c3e\u5206\u89e3\u67e5\u5b57</span> ]\uff1a\u6bd4\u5fc5(bibi)\n\u3000[ <span class="b">\u6c49\u5b57\u90e8\u4ef6\u6784\u9020</span> ]\uff1a\u6bd4\u5fc5\n<br>[ <span class="b">\u7b14\u987a\u7f16\u53f7</span> ]\uff1a153545434<br>\n[ <span class="b">\u7b14\u987a\u8bfb\u5199</span> ]\uff1a\u6a2a\u6298\u6487\u6298\u637a\u6298\u637a\u6487\u637a<br>\n<br><hr class="hr"></div>']
[u'<div class="content16">\r\n<span class="zi18b">\u25ce \u57fa\u672c\u89e3\u91ca</span><br>\r\n\u6bd6 <br>b\xec <br>\u8c28\u614e\uff1a\u60e9\u524d\u6bd6\u540e\uff08\u63a5\u53d7\u8fc7\u53bb\u5931\u8d25\u7684\u6559\u8bad\uff0c\u4ee5\u540e\u5c0f\u5fc3\u4e0d\u91cd\u72af\uff09\u3002 <br>\u64cd\u52b3\uff1a\u201c\u65e0\u6bd6\u4e8e\u6064\u201d\u3002 <br>\u53e4\u540c\u201c\u6ccc\u201d\uff0c\u6cc9\u6c34\u5192\u51fa\u6d41\u6dcc\u7684\u6837\u5b50\u3002 <br> <br>\u7b14\u753b\u6570\uff1a9\uff1b <br>\u90e8\u9996\uff1a\u6bd4\uff1b <br>\u7b14\u987a\u7f16\u53f7\uff1a153545434 <br><br><br>\r\n</div>'] [u'<div class="text16"><span class="zi18b">\u25ce \u5b57\u5f62\u7ed3\u6784</span><br>[ <span class="b">\u9996\u5c3e\u5206\u89e3\u67e5\u5b57</span> ]\uff1a\u6bd4\u5fc5(bibi)\n\u3000[ <span class="b">\u6c49\u5b57\u90e8\u4ef6\u6784\u9020</span> ]\uff1a\u6bd4\u5fc5\n<br>[ <span class="b">\u7b14\u987a\u7f16\u53f7</span> ]\uff1a153545434<br>\n[ <span class="b">\u7b14\u987a\u8bfb\u5199</span> ]\uff1a\u6a2a\u6298\u6487\u6298\u637a\u6298\u637a\u6487\u637a<br>\n<br><hr class="hr"></div>']
[u'<div class="content16">\r\n<span class="zi18b">\u25ce \u57fa\u672c\u89e3\u91ca</span><br>\r\n\u6bd6 <br>b\xec <br>\u8c28\u614e\uff1a\u60e9\u524d\u6bd6\u540e\uff08\u63a5\u53d7\u8fc7\u53bb\u5931\u8d25\u7684\u6559\u8bad\uff0c\u4ee5\u540e\u5c0f\u5fc3\u4e0d\u91cd\u72af\uff09\u3002 <br>\u64cd\u52b3\uff1a\u201c\u65e0\u6bd6\u4e8e\u6064\u201d\u3002 <br>\u53e4\u540c\u201c\u6ccc\u201d\uff0c\u6cc9\u6c34\u5192\u51fa\u6d41\u6dcc\u7684\u6837\u5b50\u3002 <br> <br>\u7b14\u753b\u6570\uff1a9\uff1b <br>\u90e8\u9996\uff1a\u6bd4\uff1b <br>\u7b14\u987a\u7f16\u53f7\uff1a153545434 <br><br><br>\r\n</div>'] [u'<div class="text16"><span class="zi18b">\u25ce \u5b57\u5f62\u7ed3\u6784</span><br>[ <span class="b">\u9996\u5c3e\u5206\u89e3\u67e5\u5b57</span> ]\uff1a\u6bd4\u5fc5(bibi)\n\u3000[ <span class="b">\u6c49\u5b57\u90e8\u4ef6\u6784\u9020</span> ]\uff1a\u6bd4\u5fc5\n<br>[ <span class="b">\u7b14\u987a\u7f16\u53f7</span> ]\uff1a153545434<br>\n[ <span class="b">\u7b14\u987a\u8bfb\u5199</span> ]\uff1a\u6a2a\u6298\u6487\u6298\u637a\u6298\u637a\u6487\u637a<br>\n<br><hr class="hr"></div>']
[u'<div class="content16">\r\n<span class="zi18b">\u25ce \u57fa\u672c\u89e3\u91ca</span><br>\r\n\u6bd6 <br>b\xec <br>\u8c28\u614e\uff1a\u60e9\u524d\u6bd6\u540e\uff08\u63a5\u53d7\u8fc7\u53bb\u5931\u8d25\u7684\u6559\u8bad\uff0c\u4ee5\u540e\u5c0f\u5fc3\u4e0d\u91cd\u72af\uff09\u3002 <br>\u64cd\u52b3\uff1a\u201c\u65e0\u6bd6\u4e8e\u6064\u201d\u3002 <br>\u53e4\u540c\u201c\u6ccc\u201d\uff0c\u6cc9\u6c34\u5192\u51fa\u6d41\u6dcc\u7684\u6837\u5b50\u3002 <br> <br>\u7b14\u753b\u6570\uff1a9\uff1b <br>\u90e8\u9996\uff1a\u6bd4\uff1b <br>\u7b14\u987a\u7f16\u53f7\uff1a153545434 <br><br><br>\r\n</div>'] [u'<div class="text16"><span class="zi18b">\u25ce \u5b57\u5f62\u7ed3\u6784</span><br>[ <span class="b">\u9996\u5c3e\u5206\u89e3\u67e5\u5b57</span> ]\uff1a\u6bd4\u5fc5(bibi)\n\u3000[ <span class="b">\u6c49\u5b57\u90e8\u4ef6\u6784\u9020</span> ]\uff1a\u6bd4\u5fc5\n<br>[ <span class="b">\u7b14\u987a\u7f16\u53f7</span> ]\uff1a153545434<br>\n[ <span class="b">\u7b14\u987a\u8bfb\u5199</span> ]\uff1a\u6a2a\u6298\u6487\u6298\u637a\u6298\u637a\u6487\u637a<br>\n<br><hr class="hr"></div>']
```

Comment: there are indentation errors in the code you shared.

Comment: still errors after the "for"

Comment: hmm, ok, i think that should do it. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution is to correct your parse function as this one. No need of the outside loop since there is just one div_a1 element in the html code.

```
class Spider(BaseSpider):
    name = "hzIII"
    allowed_domains = ["tool.httpcn.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://tool.httpcn.com/Html/Zi/28/PWMETBAZTBTBBDTB.shtml"]
    def parse(self, response):
        print  response.xpath('//*[@id="div_a1"]/div[2]').extract()
        print  response.xpath('//*[@id="div_a1"]/div[3]').extract()
```

Note:
About the posted code there is a big error in the loop. `for titles in titles` will make a loop on all elements. may be you we thinking to a `for title in titles`  in any case since there is only one element with such id you do not need the loop.

Comment: also this worked: "Perhaps you don't even have to select something in the first place, and can directly apply an XPath expression to hxs."

Answer (score 2):

I *think* what you want is

```
 tester = titles.xpath('(//*[@id="div_a1"]/div[3])[1]').extract()
```

if by "limiting extraction" you meant to only retrieve the first node of the result set. But instead of doing that, perhaps it would help to find an XPath expression which only returns exactly 1 result anyway instead of always selecting the first result.

---

Or, there is a way to tackle this on the Python side of course. Not very familiar with Python, but it seems to me `tester` is kind of an array structure and it should therefore be possible to only output the first item, something similar to

```
print tester[0]
```

---

**EDIT**: Again, not familiar with Python, but if you apply an Xpath expression inside a `for` loop, it is not surprising that the output is redundant, is it? You are selecting all `p` elements and then looping over all of them, so `//*[@id="div_a1"]/div[2]` is extracted multiple times.

```
def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        root = hxs.select("/")

        retester = root.xpath('//*[@id="div_a1"]/div[2]').extract()
        tester = root.xpath('//*[@id="div_a1"]/div[3]').extract() 
        print tester, retester
```

Perhaps you don't even have to select something in the first place, and can directly apply an XPath expression to `hxs`.

Comment: that first point is for sure a good one, i'll try that out, but actually what's the trouble is it retuns the same thing again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again and again, like that, if you check out that dropbox file, it's like that, though it's right, its just too many times, you know?

Comment: @flavius_valens You mean sequences of escaped Unicode characters? But that really _is_ the content of those nodes. What did you expect the output to be?

Comment: i just want to content of the node once, but i got the content of the node multiple times. the escaped characters is good but it's sort of complicating post processing to have them many times over.

Comment: @flavius_valens Please simply answer my question. What did you expect the output to be? Edit your question to answer it.

Comment: @flavius_valens Edited my answer. Have a look.

Comment: @Mathias Müller Have you tried the code ? It generates an error

Comment: @aberna No, I did not try it and am unfamiliar with Python, as stated multiple times in my answer. I'd be glad if you could point out and correct the error.

Comment: hi, please forgive me, python is sensitive to indentation and it was getting messed up as I copied it in, i just fixed it again, should work now.

Comment: hmm, that's a great intuition about the for loop, but still it returns things multiple copies even with your fix... strange

Comment: @MathiasMüller I understand you are not familiar with python code but your code generates errors since it invoke a not declared element

Comment: @aberna If you meant the `root` instead of `titles`, why not simply tell me? It's very unhelpful to only say that "there are errors".

Comment: @MathiasMüller I was checking an aswer too to the question so I tested your solution. After I understood what the problem was. It is quite hard to give solutions if you do not compile the code you are posting. It was quite hard to correct the errors in the Python code from Flavius_valens and check even the errors in the proposed solutions.

Comment: @aberna I have said multiple times now that I am not familiar with Python and that I therefore _can't_ compile the code (because I would need to know how to instantiate the class, for example). I wrote an answer because I am familiar with **XPath** and often, it is unclear at first if there is a Python problem or an XPath problem.

Comment: @MathiasMüller herr matthias this idea "Perhaps you don't even have to select something in the first place, and can directly apply an XPath expression to hxs." was spot on EXACTLY correct. I don't know what to do because you and aberna both settled on the solution in quick succession, i selected his answer because i think it's quite clear for people with a similar problem and as i was going off the scrapy demo i think there might be some but i upvoted your because it's great. are you ok with that choice? technically you got it first, maybe i should select yours, but you have more rep than he

Comment: @MathiasMüller The question proposed contains many errors in python. I understand you were trying to solve the issue but giving solutions without testing seems not a good approach. You both spent a lot of time in the discussion and rediting the solution. I vote a +1 on your solution since you worked hard on it.

Comment: @flavius_valens Yes, I'm sure aberna's answer is much simpler than mine - and it should be the accepted answer.